# Eclipse Oxygen - Problems / Console / Search view grayed out

Tags: eclipse

Any idea what could be causing my Eclipse Oxygen's Console / Problems / Search views to be grayed out?  It is not displaying those views when I clicked on them

[image: General View Options]

Comment: This normally means they are already open. Possibly you have minimized the folder containing those views.

Comment: Not sure what happened.  But those views are now available after I closed the Java Perspective and re-open it.  Weird.  It's almost like it didn't know that my java perspective is opened.